# How to remove Exchange data from a user's phone without remote wiping it?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, iphone, activesync

Firstly, I apologize if this is in the wrong forum; I didn't see one that clearly pertained to mobile administration. This is for an iPhone since that's relevant.

I will be assisting in the termination of a user that uses their own, personal phone for Exchange 2007. I'd like to get all the contacts/calendar/email data off of their phone, but Remote Wipe is a murky option since it isn't a company phone. The solution I'm currently looking at is using an Outlook client to export their OST to a PST, then wiping everything from their account with that client, in the hopes that the phone would then sync the now-empty profile; a few hours later we could just change the user's AD password and then do mail forwarding. I'm still very new to Exchange though, and I feel there's probably a better way to do this that I'm missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't forget to delete all their backups, too.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Not sure there is a "better" way to do it, considering that it's not company hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Without a third-party app, yes; you're right.  The only thing I'd change is start the forwarding first, then dump and delete, then disable AD account or change its password.